# Failed to fetch https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb/dists/xenial/InRelease Connection timed out after 120000 milliseconds

Tags: apt, package-management, couchdb

There is a CouchDB version `1.6.0` on Ubuntu repositories, but I need to install CouchDB `2.1.1` version. I'm following [this guide](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/unix.html#installation-using-the-apache-couchdb-convenience-binary-packages) to Install CouchDB 2.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I've done these steps:

```
$ echo "deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial main"     | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The above command adds the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial main
```

Then, to install the repository key, I run:

```
$ curl -L https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/bintray-pubkey.asc \
>     | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then I run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

**However** I receive the following error:

> Failed to fetch
>   https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb/dists/xenial/InRelease 
>   Connection timed out after 120000 milliseconds

When I check the above fetch-link, I see that there is no `InRelease` file, instead there is a `Release` file, as shown in the following screenshot. Now I wonder how I can fix this error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up compiling the CouchDB 2.1.1 from source and adding it to `systemd` as a service. It was pretty straight-forward and smooth, following [these instructions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/unix.html#installation-from-source).

---

I added CouchDB to systemd by creating the following script at `/etc/systemd/system/couchdb.service`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/couchdb/couchdb/bin/couchdb
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=couchdb
User=couchdb
Group=couchdb
Environment=

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```